# Show div after scroll and hide div at the end of the page

Tags: javascript

I try to show a div after scrolling down 1500px and i want to hide the div when 90% of the page is scrolled (so, nearly at the end of the page).

My Code works fine to show it up after 1500px but i don't know how to hide it when the end of the page is reached.

This is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #sample {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;    
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    display:none;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      var y = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (y > 1500) {
        $('#sample').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('#sample').fadeOut();
      }
    });
</script>
<div id="sample">
    just some content...
</div>
```

I would be very glad if someone can help me with the problem. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var y = $(this).scrollTop();

if (y > 1500 && y < ($(document).height() * 0.9)) {
  $('#sample').fadeIn();
} else {
  $('#sample').fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: Ok this one seems to be the easiest and shortest solution and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the "90%"-scroll with [$(window).height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [$(document).height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/). See the example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if ((y + $(window).height()) > ($(document).height() * 0.9)) {
      $('#sample').fadeOut();
      return;
    }

    if (y > 1500) {
      $('#sample').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#sample').fadeOut();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.content {
  height: 3000px;
}

#sample {
  background: #ff0000;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  Content
</div>
<div id="sample">
  sample
</div>
```